# ES2016 Class, Sinon Stub Constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon, babeljs

I'm trying to stub out a super call with sinon, and es2016 but I'm not having much luck. Any ideas why this isn't working?

Running Node 6.2.2, this might be an issue with its implementation of classes/constructors.

.babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2016"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs",
    "transform-async-to-generator"
  ]
}
```

Test:

```
import sinon from 'sinon';

class Foo {
  constructor(message) {
    console.log(message)
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  constructor() {
    super('test');
  }
}

describe('Example', () => {
  it('should stub super.constructor call', () => {
    sinon.stub(Foo.prototype, 'constructor');

    new Bar();

    sinon.assert.calledOnce(Foo.prototype.constructor);
  });
});
```

Result:

```
test
AssertError: expected constructor to be called once but was called 0 times
    at Object.fail (node_modules\sinon\lib\sinon\assert.js:110:29)
    at failAssertion (node_modules\sinon\lib\sinon\assert.js:69:24)
    at Object.assert.(anonymous function) [as calledOnce] (node_modules\sinon\lib\sinon\assert.js:94:21)
    at Context.it (/test/classtest.spec.js:21:18)
```

**Note**: this issue seems to only happen for constructors. I can spy on methods inherited from the parent class without any issues.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You'll need to setPrototypeOf the subClass due to the way JavaScript implements inheritance.

```js
const sinon = require("sinon");

class Foo {
  constructor(message) {
    console.log(message);
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  constructor() {
    super('test');
  }
}

describe('Example', () => {
  it('should stub super.constructor call', () => {
    const stub = sinon.stub().callsFake();
    Object.setPrototypeOf(Bar, stub);

    new Bar();

    sinon.assert.calledOnce(stub);
  });
});
```

Comment: How is this checking that super was called? It seems to be checking that Bar's constructor was called, not that Foo's constructor was called.

Comment: Great example, however using Object.setPrototypeOf() will change the prototype of the class Bar and cause an issue in the succeeding tests that come after it. After the test prototype of Bar should be Foo.

Comment: I expanded your example here, that addresses setting back the original parent class: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67458816/6375464

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52286046/6375464) of Wenshan, there is one step that may be overlooked when stubbing the parent class and replacing the original parent class with `setPrototypeOf`.

Additionally, to avoid it breaking the succeeding tests it is a good idea to **set back the original parent class** at the end, like:

```js
const sinon = require("sinon");
    
class Foo {
  constructor(message) {
    console.log(message);
   }
}
    
class Bar extends Foo {
  constructor() {
    super('test');
  }
}
    
describe('Bar constructor', () => {
  it('should call super', () => {
    const stub = sinon.stub().callsFake();
    const original = Object.getPrototypeOf(Bar);  // Bar.__proto__ === Foo
    

    Object.setPrototypeOf(Bar, stub);             // Bar.__proto__ === stub
    
    new Bar();
    
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(stub);
    Object.setPrototypeOf(Bar, original);         // Bar.__proto__ === Foo

  });
});
```

The addition is

```js
// saving the reference to the original parent class:
const original = Object.getPrototypeOf(Bar);
```

```js
// setting back the original parent class after stubbing and the assertion:
Object.setPrototypeOf(Bar, original);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `spy` instead of `stub`,

`sinon.spy(Foo.prototype, 'constructor');`

```
describe('Example', () => {
  it('should stub super.constructor call', () => {
    const costructorSpy = sinon.spy(Foo.prototype, 'constructor');
    new Bar();
    expect(costructorSpy.callCount).to.equal(1);
  });
});
```

*****Update******
Above was not working as expected, I added this way and is working now.

```
 describe('Example', () => {
    it('should stub super.constructor call', () => {
      const FooStub = spy(() => sinon.createStubInstance(Foo));
      expect(FooStub).to.have.been.calledWithNew;
    });
 });
```

Comment: Interesting this didn't work for me:

`AssertionError: expected 0 to equal 1`

 - I copied your example above.

Comment: Hmm... It is interesting, updated with new changes.. Think that is a workaround :)

Comment: Your new example still doesn't seem to work with my node 6.2.2 and babel es2016 preset.

Comment: `createStubInstance` is no more in Sinon

Comment: [`createStubInstance`](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/utils/#sinoncreatestubinstanceconstructor) is back in place

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a browser environment, the following works too:

```
let constructorSpy = sinon.spy(window, 'ClassName');
```

For example this would work with Jasmine.

Mocha instead runs in Node environment, there is no `window`. The variable you'd be looking for is `global`

Answer (score -1):

It doesn’t work for me either. I managed a workaround that works for me, i use spy as well:

```
class FakeSchema {
  constructor(newCar) {
    this.constructorCallTest();
    this.name = newCar.name;
  }

  constructorCallTest() {
    mochaloggger.log('constructor was called');
  }

}

// spy that tracks the contsructor call
var fakeSchemaConstrSpy = sinon.spy(FakeCarSchema.prototype,'constructorCallTest');
```

Hope that was helpful