# How to stub an extended ES6 class' constructor with Sinon

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, sinon

So I'm having a few issues with stubbing constructors, and more-so inherited classes constructors...
I'll start with some sample code snippets:

Parent.js

```
module.exports = class Parent {
  constructor (){
    // code I don't want to run during tests
  }
}
```

MyClass.js

```
let Parent = require('path/to/Parent');

module.exports = class MyClass extends Parent {
  // no overridden constructor
}
```

Mocha Test

```
let MyClass = require('path/to/MyClass')

...

test('test1', (done) => {
  // I want to stub the MyClass/Parent constructor before creating a new instance
  // of MyClass so that the constructor code in Parent doesn't run

  let myClass = new MyClass();
  // assertions 'n' stuff
  return done();
});

...
```

I've tried a few things already but always find that the code in Parent constructor gets run regardless of what I do... I have a feeling it might have something to do with MyClass requiring Parent before a get a chance to stub it.

I've also tried using rewire to replace the variable in MyClass, but not joy there either; e.g.

```
let MyClass = rewire('path/to/MyClass');
MyClass.__set__('Parent', sinon.stub());
```

Any suggestions/help on how I might achieve what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ES2016 Class, Sinon Stub Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40271140/es2016-class-sinon-stub-constructor)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used rewire so I'm not sure why it doesn't work but stubbing the parent constructor would work fine using [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire):

```
const MockParent = sinon.stub()
const MyClass = proxyquire('../../some/path', {
  './Parent': MockParent
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = class MyClass extends Parent {
  // no overridden constructor
}
```

Be equal to:

```
module.exports = class MyClass extends Parent {
  constructor (...args) {
     super(...args) // be equal to Parent.call(this, ...args)
  }
}
```

So, the processes are new MyClass() -> MyClass constructor() -> Parent.call() -> Parent constructor()

Answer (score 0):

[I'm not sure if this is the most modern way to do it](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/1892#issuecomment-1878007472), but [I found this solution from a Sinon contributor](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/1892#issuecomment-420063432).

I've converted their code into a passing test:

```
import sinon from "sinon";

describe("Stubbing parent constructor but not child constructor", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });

  it(`can intercept parent calls`, () => {
    let classAConstructorCalled = false;
    let classBConstructorCalled = false;
    let stubCalledFake = false;

    class A {
      constructor() {
        classAConstructorCalled = true;
      }
    }

    class B extends A {
      constructor() {
        super();
        classBConstructorCalled = true;
      }
    }

    Object.setPrototypeOf(
      B,
      sinon.stub().callsFake(function () {
        stubCalledFake = true;
      })
    );

    new B();

    expect(classAConstructorCalled).toBeFalse();
    expect(classBConstructorCalled).toBeTrue();
    expect(stubCalledFake).toBeTrue();
  });
});
```

Note: You should reset the modified prototype if you plan to use that class (e.g., `B`) elsewhere:

```js
afterEach(() => {
  sinon.restore();
  Object.setPrototypeOf(
    B,
    originalPrototype // get this with `originalPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(B);` in your beforeEach
  );
});
```